# Firefox Web Extension API - Get Downloads Folder

Tags: api, download, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is it possible using the web extensions API to get the default download folder for the current profile?  I need to send it via native messaging to an external app.

I feel like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads should have it but it does't seem to.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably making a dummy download and sending the "filename" property that you get back as a variable to your external app.

You would use the browser.downloads.onChanged event to get a reference to the filename value:

```
browser.downloads.onChanged.addListener(listener);

function listener(changed){
    if(changed.filename != null){
        // Do something

        // Remove downloads.onChanged listener
        browser.downloads.onChanged.removeListener(listener);
    }
}

browser.downloads.download({url: dummyUrl});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/onChanged